# Match gcc -L compiler arguments -- Expressions, with whitespaces only if they are surrounded with apostrophes

Tags: regex, gcc, arguments, whitespace, apostrophe

Suppose that I have some gcc command line like this one below:

```
gcc main.c -o main -lwhatever -lsomeother -Lpath/to/whatever -L"/path to the/someotherlib"
```

How can I match `path/to/whatever` and `"/path to the/someotherlib"` (either with or without the apostrophes)?

Probably I should use some lookarounds but I fail to figure out how exactly.

I started to build an expression like the one below

```
(?<=-L)(.*)(?=\s)
```

Then I added the apostrophes:

```
(?<=-L)"?(.*)"?(?=\s)
```

Turns out I cannot solve the problem that way, because `.*` matches any character and somehow clashes with `\s` in the lookbehind (maybe it consumes it but I think I even have to be careful with this statement).

If I put `[^\s]` in the place of `.`, then it would not count whether the expression is between apostrophes or not, the match would end at the first whitespace.

[image]

Comment: Can't do it that way. There are 2 distinct things here, it can't be combined in a generalization. That means at least 2 capture groups. And the assertions are ludicrous since you just need to concat the 2 groups to get the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value can be obtained by concantinating groups 2 and 3.

`\s-L(?:(["'])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1|(\S*))`

https://regex101.com/r/uYnUTA/1
or https://regex101.com/r/mBp1eH/1

```
 \s -L                # whitespace then -L param 
 (?:                  # One of these values
    ( ["'] )             # (1), quote delimiter
    (                    # (2 start)
       (?:                  # content within quotes
          (?! \1 )             # Not a quote
          .                    # this char is ok
       )*                   # do 0 to many
    )                    # (2 end)
    \1                   # backref to quote
  | ( \S* )              # (3), Or, non-quote parameter
 )
```

Note that any special escaping of possible delimiter quotes inside the quote can be done as well.
Just not done here.